# jQuery How to clone() more than one time

Tags: jquery, clone, prepend

i'v clone some elements list, but i need to clone it more than one time, can you tell me how to do it?

```
$('.main_content ul li').clone().prependTo('.main_content ul')
```

Much thx for help.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question about an hour ago? It's deleted

Comment: Just call `.clone()` again...?

Comment: it's not the same question, and i can't find similar... when i call again it dosn't work

Comment: do you need multiple clone's or prepend 1 clone multiple times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this maybe?

```
var objToClone = $('.main_content ul li');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   objToClone.clone().prependTo('.main_content ul');
```

Comment: `$('.main_content ul li')` is not a single object

Comment: and? he needed to clone some jquery object, not single LIElement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, you want to clone listed tags into it's same parent? This will result in the same listed items being in the same parent.

Or do you want to clone the parent? Or do you want to clone only certain listed items?

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div class="main_content">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var numberOfCopies = 5;

        for(x = 0; x < numberOfCopies; x++){
            $(".main_content ul li").each(function(){
                $(this).clone().appendTo(".main_content ul");
            });
        }
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of using .prependTo() replace that with .insertAfter()

for example:

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    for () {
        $('.main_content ul li').clone().insertAfter('.main_content ul li');
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx9Tu/)